# Error Message after closing Qt creator 5 : "Unexpected CDB error"

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator

Even after just creating a simple new project, sometimes after exiting qt creator it closes with the message **"Unexpected CDB Error "**. As it's related to debugger, I have tried with fresh installation of debugger many times, it still closes with the same error.

Any one having any idea about this?

Comment: Is the option "QML debugging and profiling" enabled? That might be the cause of this error

Comment: Are you able to use the debugger before quitting Qt Creator? There's not enough info here for more than a basic Google search.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the message box?

Answer (score 0):

It's a well known issue that has been fix with Qt Creator 3.6.0:

[ISSUE #15456](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-15456)

As state by @alexis-p, When you uncheck "Enable QML debugging and profiling", Creator 3.6 shouldn't show the warning.

Hope this helped.

Comment: I already have done this, but 2 out of 10 times it gives me the same error in Qt creator 5.5.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean there as the latest version of Qt Creator is 3.6.x ! Just upgrade Qt Creator to the latest version and try again.

Comment: UPDATE: Actually as of today (10/05/2016), they've just released version 4.0 with Qt 5.6